# How to configure azure-cli behind a corporate proxy on Windows

Tags: windows, proxy, azure-cli

I'm using Windows 10 behind a corporate proxy and `az --version` outputs the following:

```
azure-cli                          2.5.1

command-modules-nspkg              2.0.3
core                               2.5.1
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.4
...
Unable to check if your CLI is up-to-date. Check your internet connection.
```

Furthermore, `az extension list-available` throws:

```
Unable to get extension index.
Please ensure you have network connection. Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aka.ms', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /azure-cli-extension-index-v1 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))
```

How to configure azure-cli for the corporate proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download local proxy configuration from http://wpad/wpad.dat
2. At the beginning of the `wpad.dat` file there is a line similar to `CWSProxy="PROXY proxy.corporation.com:8082";`
3. Enter the proxy server to environment variable HTTPS_PROXY, e.g. in bash: `export HTTPS_PROXY="proxy.corporation.com:8082"`

Now `az extension list-available` connects. However, for some reason, `az --version` is still giving `Unable to check if your CLI is up-to-date. Check your internet connection.` You can now anyway install extensions such as `az extension add --name azure-devops`.

Comment: This answer helps me, and resolve the question, you can mark it resolved

Comment: Useful answer. In my case I had to set `HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.corporation.com:80"` (either PowerShell or bash worked).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest&tabs=azure-cli#proxy-blocks-connection

For Windows 10, you could check the proxy settings in the `Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy` pane. Contact your system administrator for the required settings, or for situations where your machine may be configuration-managed or require advanced setup.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It helps to find the proxy yes but doesn't resolve the trouble.