# Installing biceps with azure cli, getting SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate _ssl.c:1125

Tags: azure, devops, azure-cli, azure-bicep

Getting the following error:

az_command_data_logger: Error while attempting to retrieve the latest Bicep version: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /repos/Azure/bicep/releases/latest (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)'))).

Tried the following. But not working
1)created REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE and pointed to .pem file which I generated by downloading from api.github.com  [.crt] .

2)https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/3147

3)https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/19420.

I am using latest version of Azure CLI 2.31.0

Comment: Could you please share us the command that you are using.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue i have tried with latest version of Azure-cli 2.31.0 using cmd    ` az bicep install` it got successfully installed [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/meymy.png  Could you please help us to know bit more details .

Comment: C:\Users\r>az bicep install Error while attempting to retrieve the latest Bicep version: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /repos/Azure/bicep/releases/latest (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)'))).    Also I am working inside a cooperate proxy

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691475/how-to-configure-azure-cli-behind-a-corporate-proxy-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @TrevorBrooks, here are the few workarounds to resolve the above issue
As you are using Corporate proxy :

- Azure CLI must pass an authentication payload over the `HTTPS` request due to the authentication design of Azure Service, which will be blocked at authentication time at your corporate proxy. When you use e.g: `az login`, you will get a TIMEOUT notification, which is normal.

To configure Azure cli with co-operate proxy :

- You can add  `_HTTPS_PROXY_` environment variable.
- To know about what proxy you are using, You can refer [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using#346376).

For example :

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.name:8080
```

- Simply add the aforementioned variable to your environment variables for a permanent solution.
  [image]

**NOTE: After adding the environment variable ,need to reboot the Terminal .**

For more information please refer this [Blog](https://blog.jhnr.ch/2017/09/24/use-azure-cli-with-corporate-proxy-server/) .