# Install Bicep cli in coporate laptop error

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-bicep

I am trying to install bicep cli, I am using coporate laptop, I get the following error
I tried with and without VPN and get the same error:
My Azure CLI version is: 2.44.1 and I am using windows 10

```
 Error while attempting to retrieve the latest Bicep version: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aka.ms', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /BicepLatestRelease (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)'))).
```

I searched the net these answers didn't solve my problem ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70301778/installing-biceps-with-azure-cli-getting-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certifi) and [enter link description here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20842)

Comment: It appears that some server is presenting an untrusted "self signed certificate in certificate chain". Do you have to use a proxy server? Is this server configured on your laptop's OS? What happens if you navigate to https://aka.ms/BicepLatestRelease with a web browser?

Comment: it downloads a file latest

Comment: Check Julian's answer. As I suspected, the problem is with your proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are sitting behind a HTTPS intercepting proxy.
You should reach out to your enterprise IT to resolve this.

Get the CA Certificates used by the proxy, save them locally and tell the Azure CLI where to find it:

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Your IT might also be able to except Azure and GitHub from HTTPS interception.

**Security Risk**
You can also disable the certificate verification. But it is not recommended and will be a security risk.

```
export AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION=anycontent
```